# Get records from last 6 Months MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have around 1,000 records in a table.

They're all timestamped in the format `2020-05-20 06:18:30`.

When I try to run the following, it just grabs **anything**, even some records going back to 2018.

```
SELECT * FROM goals WHERE submitted_timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) LIMIT 20
```

Where am I going wrong with the above query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have checked this and working fine for me and it's not displaying the any 2018 year data so can you please provide the some records on which you have problem?

```
SELECT *,now(),DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) FROM goals WHERE submitted_timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much, Akash! :-)